# How can I make a list item clickable?

Tags: html, html-lists, html-table

I have been playing with different way to display data and have been looking into taking the actual data out of a table and displaying it in unordered lists.  This gives me greater flexibility in what I can do with the markup.

However there is one thing that I'm having a think about - how do you make the row (or UL in this case) clickable?

I don't want to use any JavaScript so my first thought was something like this:

```
<div class="liTable">
<ul class="headerRow">
    <li class="cell col-1">title1</li>
    <li class="cell col-2">title2</li>
    <li class="cell col-3">title3</li>
    <li class="cell col-3">title4</li>
</ul>
<a href=”myURL”>
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="cell col-1">1</li>
        <li class="cell col-2">2</li>
        <li class="cell col-3">3</li>
        <li class="cell col-3">4</li>
    </ul>
</a></div>
```

But this mark-up is illegal because you cannot place ul's inside links.

Any ideas or suggestions on best practice for this?

Comment: If you are displaying Tabular data then display in a Table. Otherwise use some other way. Don't try and re-invent the Table.

Comment: If you are using html5 you are allowed to put block level elements inside an anchor tag http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes

Comment: and putting tabular data into lists? I guess your not bothered about accessibility then as your data is going to make no sense when read by screen readers

Comment: Glad to know you can place block level elements into anchor tags so thanks Pete.  I am using HTML5 schema so this should be OK.  I am also aware of the accessibility issues, but I'm not too concerned with this because the software is internal.  Tabular data should be placed in a table, but I need more flexibility in the mark-up so this was the work around I thought about.  Thanks for your input everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please put tabular data into a table and list data into lists, that's what they are for after all.

You can make any element call up a URL by adding

```
 onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';"
```

to the tag, but be aware that there's no right-click options for this and you'll need to style the element to make it obvious it's a link.

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/WguUR/

---

But would it not be enough to enclose the content of the table field in an "a" like this?

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.example.com">January</a></td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It certainly makes sense to put tabular data in lists sometimes because they can be made responsive, whereas tables cannot.

Comment: Actually tables can be made responsive @MathiasBader. You can overwrite the default display characteristics of tables and their children. For example:

    table, tr, td{
         display:block;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do the following?

```
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in JS there is an onclick prop you can add to any DOM element. Either that or wrap your element in a anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Wrapping a list item in a link tag would create invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

as @spiel mentioned I think this is the best reach to your requirements.

**Source Code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="liTable">
        <ul class="headerRow">
            <li class="cell col-1">title1</li>
            <li class="cell col-2">title2</li>
            <li class="cell col-3">title3</li>
            <li class="cell col-3">title4</li>
        </ul>
        <a>
            <ul class="row">
                <li class="cell col-1", onclick="location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495538/how-can-i-make-a-list-item-clickable';">1</li>
                <li class="cell col-2">2</li>
                <li class="cell col-3">3</li>
                <li class="cell col-3">4</li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```